# Why can't I pull the latest fmriprep singularity version?

Tags: docker, development-environment, hpc, singularity-container

I tried to pull the latest version of the Singularity image for fmriprep into an HPC, which to my understanding is 21.0.1.

I did it using the following bash script:

```
module load singularity
singularity pull --name fmriprep_latest.sif docker://poldracklab/fmriprep:latest
```

Unfortunately, for some reason, it pulled a very old and deprecated version of fmriprep.

In addition, when I try to write a specific version (e.g., `docker://poldracklab/fmriprep:20.2.3`) I get an error message saying that the manifest is unknown.

Any idea for how can I pull the latest version?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify a different registry, Singularity fetches the image from Docker Hub. It is pulling the tags you specify, but the images available on Docker Hub are quite old.

https://hub.docker.com/r/poldracklab/fmriprep/tags

Answer (score 0):

This may be a little late. But I had the same issue. To draw on what @tsnowlan says above, you can obtain the image from the nipreps registry. Here is what I used:

```
singularity build fmriprep-21.0.1.simg docker://nipreps/fmriprep:21.0.1
```